# Drupal Commerce charge customer after an event

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I have a Drupal Commerce site, on that site, I want to sell live streaming sessions. I would like to know, how I can charge to the user after that event, according with the time of the session.

I'm not sure if exists a way to link PayPal customer accounts with my site for make charges automatically, without additional user actions.